# creating composite foreign key from two different tables primary keys in oracle

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

**table1:**

*tid(primary key)* // no foreign keys here

**table2:**

*sid(primary key)* // no foreign keys here too

**table3:**

```
 Tid
 Sid
 iid(primary key)
 foreign key(Tid,Sid) references table1(tid).table2(sid)

 In table3 i want to make a composite foreign key or composite foreign key constraint but failed . there are many questions related to this .But none of them seems helpful to me . How can i do that ? Is it valid ? Then what is the syntax of making composite foreign key from two different tables primary key
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve. Isn't easier to just create two separate foreign keys to the two tables?

Comment: I want to create a foreign key from two different primary keys from different tables

Comment: It cannot be done. You can only create two separate foreign keys, each one referencing one primary key in a given table.

Comment: It makes no sense to have a single foreing key to two different tables. It makes sense to have two separate foreing keys to the two tables

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a single foreign key referencing fields on different tables, and it makes no sense at all. A foreign key of two or more fields implies that the combination of values of the fields must be match on a single record of the referenced table, and this can't be done if the referenced fields are on different tables.

What you can do is to create two distinct foreing keys to the two tables, as following:

```
CREATE TABLE table3(
    iid NUMBER,
    Tid NUMBER,
    Sid NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT pk    PRIMARY KEY (iid) USING INDEX TABLESPACE idx,
    CONSTRAINT fk001 FOREIGN KEY (tid) REFERENCES table1(tid),
    CONSTRAINT fk002 FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES table2(sid)
);
```